# CakePHP - Use find() method

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I have an `Artist` model and a `Product` model. Their associations are as follows:

```
Artist hasMany Product
Product belongsTo Artist
```

An `Artist` may not have any `Products`. How do I use the `find()` method to list all artists along with the number of `Products` they have?

Comment: did you mean the "COUNT()" of products??

Answer (score 1):

as long as your relationships are set up properly, this is all you need to do.

```
$results = $ArtistModel->find('all');
```

Answer (score 1):

From artist controller you can do this:

```
$this->Artist->find('all')
```

To access it in a view you will need to use set() like this:

```
$this->set('artists', $this->Artist->find('all'));
```

You can then see the data by doing `print_r($artists);` in a view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `find` call like this:

```
$artists = $this->Artist->find('all');
```

which returns and array like this:

```
array(
  [0] => array(
    [Artist] => array(
      'id' => 1,
      'other_field' => 'other_value',
      ...
    ),
    [Product] => array(
      [0] => array(
        'id' => 1,
        ...
      ),
      [1] => array(
        'id' => 2,
        ...
      )

    )
  )
  [1] => array(
    [Artist] => array(
      'id' => 2,
      'other_field' => 'other_value',
      ...
    ),
    [Product] => array(...)
  )
)
```

You can then iterate over the results and get the information you need:

```
foreach ( $artists as $artist ) {
  echo $artist['Artist']['name'];
  echo count($artist['Product']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [counterCache](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1033/counterCache-Cache-your-count) function to store on cache the number of products per Artist.

Or if you want to, you could (manually) use the ORM, it should be something like:

```
$this->Artist->find('all',array('fields'=>array('Artist.*','COUNT(Product.id) as count_products')
                                'joins'=>array(array('table' => 'products',
                                                     'alias' => 'Product',
                                                     'type' => 'INNER',
                                                     'conditions' => array('Artist.id = Product.artist_id'))),
                                'group'=>'Artist.id'
));
```

Hope this helps